# What's wrong with this program? It doesn't run properly

Tags: c

I tried making a simple program on codeblocks that gets max 50 numbers and puts them into an array. It stops if you type -1 or 0. After that, it prints out all the numbers you typed in.

Codeblock says everything is correct and that there are no errors. When I run the program, nothing appears: the screen is black.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int usernumbers[i];
    const N = 50;

    printf("write an integer (-1 or 0 to stop)\n");
    scanf("%d", usernumbers[i]);

    while(usernumbers[i] != -1 && usernumbers[i] != 0){
        for( i=0; i<N; i++){
            printf("Next number: \n");
            scanf("%d", usernumbers[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("The numbers you entered are: \n");

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d", usernumbers[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

Comment: `int usernumbers[i];` you are defining the array length with garbage value of `i`

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work

Comment: `int i; int usernumbers[i];`  has undefined behaviour since `i` is uninitialised.     It doesn't create an array that magically resizes itself whenever `i` is changed, which (I infer from your subsequent code) is what you are expecting.

Comment: MSVC produced some warnings: crank up your warning level.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Always initialize your vars before use.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int N = 50;

    // initialize your array with zero's
    int userNumbers[N] = { 0 };

    printf("write an integer (-1 or 0 to stop)\n");
    // initialize the var with 0.
    int index = 0;
    // in this case I don't initialize because I will initialize below, on scanf_s
    int number;
    // Check against scanf_s result and if index is less then N, we don't want index out of bounds
    while (scanf_s("%d", &number) && index < N)
    {
        // the numbers you defined to stop
        if (number == -1 || number == 0)
            break;

        // put the number into array and add 1 to index
        userNumbers[index++] = number;
    }

    printf("The numbers you entered are: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", userNumbers[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The only thing different here is your loop. Don't make sense. You have a `while` with a for inside. Your `while` will run one time and your `for` will run N times, so to your check if the entered number is -1 or 0 will not be handled as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for and handles I/O errors
4. corrects the problems with the OPs posted code
5. does not print numbers that are not initialized by user input
6. inserts appropriate horizontal and vertical spacing for readability and ease of understanding
7. properly declares and initializes the array `usernumbers[]`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 50


int main( void )
{
    int usernumbers[ N ] = {0};


    printf("write an integer (-1 or 0 to stop)\n");
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if( scanf( "%d", &usernumbers[i] ) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to read number\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( usernumbers[i] == -1 || usernumbers[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        printf("Next number: \n");
    }

    printf("The numbers you entered are: \n");

    for( int i=0; i<N; i++ )
    {
        if( usernumbers[i] == -1 || usernumbers[i] == 0 )
        {
            break;
        }

        printf( "%d ", usernumbers[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The definition of `usernumbers`is wrong.

Also I'm surprised the line `const N = 50;` does not trigger a compiler error.

You should do something like :

```
#define N 50
int usernumbers[N];
```

Comment: Given `const N = 50;`  the compiler assumes `N` is of type `int`.  So the declaration is effectively `const int N = 50;`

Comment: Your code example won't pass any C compiler: `int username[= 50;];`

Comment: now the program works but goes into loop. It doesn't stop when you put 0 or -1.

Comment: @harper, yes sorry, I copy pasted too quickly